# Mapkit and MKRoute.Step information

Tags: routes, mapkit

Has anyone seen or devised a solution to this problem?

When using Mapkit and MKDirections, I would like to know the coordinates of where I would be at the end of every route step. In other words, iterating through each route step, I would like the coordinates of the end point of that route step. I have the polyline for the route, however I am interested in where I would be during each step of the way.

Thanks for any ideas in advance.

Answer (score 0):

MKDirections 's respons has got route results such as distance, expectedTravelTime,steps. It hasnot any information about coordinate of steps, so it doesn't need. You can use "steps" of mkdirections as follow.

```
getDistance (sourceLocation : CLLocationCoordinate2D,   endLocation : CLLocationCoordinate2D,  completion: @escaping (_ distance: Double?,_ travelTime : String?) -> (Void))
{ 
var msf : Double?
var travelTime : String?
let request = MKDirections.Request()
let source = MKPlacemark( coordinate: sourceLocation) //any   location you choose
let destination = MKPlacemark( coordinate: endLocation)
request.source =  MKMapItem(placemark: source)
request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: destination)
request.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.automobile
request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true
let directions = MKDirections ( request: request)
directions.calculate { (response, error) in
if let error = error {
print("Distance directions calculation error\n \ (error.localizedDescription)")
return
}
if let route = response?.routes {
let sortedRoutes = route.sorted(by: { $0.distance < $1.distance}) 
let shortestRoute = sortedRoutes.first 
//this parts finds shortest route of directions         
print(shortestRoute?.steps) // this part writes all steps of directions  
}
completion  (msf,travelTime)
  }
}
```

when you call it gives you distance and travel time,but you can draw polyline for route and show all steps.

```
 func   findDistanceForRoute(sourceLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D, endLocation : CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    
    var dist : Double? = 0.0
    var traTime : String? = "0"
    
    getDistance(sourceLocation: sourceLocation , endLocation: endLocation)
    
    )
    { distance, travelTime  in
        
        
        guard let distance = distance else {
            return  print("an error occurs")
            
        }
        dist = (distance)
        traTime = (travelTime!)
        // you can use distance and travel time
    }
     completion(dist,traTime)
  
 }
```